# Express & Socket.io - best practice

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm now working on project with the `Express` framework, `socket.io` package and `NodeJS` on the server-side, and the `socket.io-client` on the client-side.
Here is the code example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
//...
server.listen(80);
```

I'm wondering if using the `http server`, as a result of combining `socket.io` and `Express`, may cause some limitation over the number of allowed connections to the server.

My site should persist under the usage of 1,000 connection at once.

So, the questions are:

1. Does using `http server` for listening on the port limits the connections number more than the `app` variable?
2. What is the max number of `socket.io` connections at once? are there any known problems regarding to that?
3. Does the `agentPool` of `http server` limits the connections number?
4. Does the `_maxListeners` of `http server` limits the connections number?
5. Should I use `app.listen(80)` or `server.listen(80)`? and why?

   Moreover, if you have any suggestions/ best practices or known issues when working with socket.io, Express and node.js I'll be happy to learn :-)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 5:

Default port for `HTTP` request is `80` and for `HTTPS` is `443`.

If any other port is used rather than default port then the port number has to be specified in the URL request.

Example:

domain name: `example.com`, port: `3000`. Request URL will be `http://example.com:3000`
domain name: `example.com`, port: `80`. Request URL will be `http://example.com`

Same in case of `HTTPS` request.

Not using default ports have following issues:

1. Reveals the port at which app is running.
2. Telecommunication service provider may have blocked ports other than default ports thus your app may be inaccessible.